# Application of intermediate value theorem or Borsuk-Ulam theorem on cylinder?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider  three distinct points $a,b,c$ on the top of the cylinder with anticlockwise direction. Consider other three distinct points $a',c',b'$ in the bottom of the cylinder. There are continuous paths  connecting $a$ with $a'$,$b$ with $b'$ and $c$ with $c'$. As we can see in the figure that  anticlockwise orientation of points $a',b',c'$ is changed, that is, $c'$ got in between $a'$ and $b'$ (all transformations are continuous). I do not want this happen, that is, I do not want the orientation of $a',b',c'$ to get changed. This claim will follow if I would be able to prove that we cannot connect $c$ with $c'$ by a continuous path unless we cross one of the other two paths. This will lead me to a certain contradiction and I am done.

As we can see in the diagram that the continous red path between $c$ and $c'$ must intersect one of the other either paths connecting $a$ with $a'$ or $b$ with $b'$. How to formulate this result mathematically (with equations and all) and how to prove it. I am wondering if it is the application of a generalized Intermediate value theorem or Borsuk-Ulum theorem on cylinder? I rewrite the question:

> Prove that $c$ and $c'$ cannot be connected by a continuous path $C$ unless this path $C$ intersects any of the other two paths on the cylinder.

EDIT: The path A from $a$ to $a′$ and the path B from $b$ to $b′$ do not intersect.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Assuming that the $z$-coordinate of each path is a strictly monotone function of $t$ as illustrated in the drawing, we can regard the paths as maps $\alpha, \beta, \gamma : I \to \Bbb S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$ satisfying $\alpha(0) = a', \alpha(1) = a$, etc. At the top of the cylinder, $a, b, c$ are in anticlockwise order, so the quantity $$\det\pmatrix{b - a & c - a} = (b_1 - a_1)(c_2 - a_2) - (c_1 - a_1)(b_2 - a_2)$$ is positive (its value is just twice the area of the triangle $\triangle abc$), but at the bottom of the cylinder the reverse is true.

> **Additional hint** This suggests considering the quantity $$f(t) := \det \pmatrix{\beta(t) - \alpha(t) & \gamma(t) - \alpha(t)} .$$ At $t = 0, 1$, we have $$f(0) = \det \pmatrix{b' - a' & c' - a'} < 0 , \qquad \det \pmatrix{b - a & c - a} > 0,$$ so the Intermediate Value Theorem gives that there is some time $t_0 \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(t_0) = 0$. But this implies that $b(t_0) - a(t_0)$ and $c(t_0) - a(t_0)$ are parallel, so either one is zero---which implies $a(t_0) = b(t_0)$ or $a(t_0) = c(t_0)$---or they are equal---in which case $b(t_0) = c(t_0)$.

Comment: The path A from a to a′ and the path B from b to b′ do certainly do not intersect in my question. I will edit the question. But my z-coordinate is not monotone in general. Can I fix your argument somehow for the general case?

Comment: Yes, I think there's an easy (but slightly complicating) modification to the argument that handles the general case; I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll need to think about my argument to see if there's a clean way to make it precise: Roughly, if the curves are nice (say, piecewise $C^1$ or something), you can reparameterize the paths so that when the $z$-coordinate on one of the curves is greater than that of another, it waits for the other curve to catch up. I think this can be made precise (including handling when all three paths are moving downward), but I don't see a clean way to formulate that argument yet.

Comment: Probably for the case of curves with $z$-coordinate not necessarily monotone a topological argument would be easier; in fact, it's probably trivial with the right observation from algebraic topology. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: One way to proceed along those lines would be to show that if there were paths that did not intersect, then gluing the ends of the cylinder together 'backward' would show that the Klein bottle is orientable---which is false.

Comment: Klein bottle argument would be different from what you have provided above. I like the first one. I was thinking about approximating any continuous function with a monotonic continuous functions. I wonder if that is possible.

Comment: Also, I cannot afford $C^1$ condition for my work.

Answer (score 2):

I'll also assume that:

1) The path $A$ from $a$ to $a'$ and the path $B$ from $b$ to $b'$ do not intersect, and

2) The $z$-coordinate of each path is monotone.

Assumption 1) is clearly necessary; assumption 2) is almost certainly unnecessary but makes my life a lot easier.

Suppose that $C$ does not intersect $A$. Since $B$ also does not intersect $A$, $C$ and $B$ are both paths in $S^1 \times [0,1]-A$. Because $A$ is monotone, $S^1 \times [0,1]-A$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1) \times [0,1]$.

Because $B$ and $C$ are monotone, they correspond under this homeomorphism to functions $f,g$ from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$. Because the orientations on the two edges are opposite, we have $f(0)<g(0)$ and $f(1)>g(1)$. So by the intermediate value theorem we have $f(c)=g(c)$ for some $c$, which gives an intersection between $B$ and $C$.

Comment: The path A from a to a′ and the path B from b to b′ do certainly do not intersect in my question. I will edit the question. But my z-coordinate is not monotone in general. Can I fix your argument somehow for the general case?

Comment: @mathwizard: I think Travis's determinant argument works better in the general case than any of the things I had in mind; I would go with that!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an argument using the difficult Jordan Curve Theorem that applies to the case that at least two of the curve are simple (i.e., do not have any self-intersections), say, the curves $\alpha, \beta$ respectively corresponding to $a, b$. Even failing that condition, the result can probably be recovered by replacing (with some care) the curves with suitable simple curves.

Map the cylinder $S^1 \times [0, 1] \subset \Bbb C \times [0, 1]$ to the annulus $A := \{1 \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq 2\} \subset \Bbb C$ via the homeomorphism $$\Phi: (z, s) \mapsto (s + 1) z .$$  Then construct a simple path $\delta$ from $\Phi(a)$ to $\Phi(b)$ not intersecting $A$ elsewhere and a simple path $\epsilon$ from $\Phi(a')$ to $\Phi(b')$ not intersecting $A$ elsewhere. By construction the concatenated curve $$\zeta := \Phi(\alpha) \cdot \delta \cdot \Phi(\beta^{-1}) \cdot (\epsilon^{-1})$$ is a Jordan curve in $\Bbb C$ and hence partitions $\Bbb C$ into a bounded open set $U$, the image $Z$ of $\zeta$, and an unbounded open set $V$. In particular, intersecting these three sets with $A$ gives a partition of $A$ into two open sets and the union of the images of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But $a, b, c$ and $a', b', c'$ having the relative orders indicated in the diagram implies that $\Phi(c) \in A \cap V$ but $\Phi(c') \in A \cap U$. So, if $\gamma$ is the curve from $c$ to $c'$, $\Phi \circ \gamma$ intersects the union of the images of $\Phi \circ \alpha$ and $\Phi \circ \beta$, and applying the inverse homeomorphism gives that $\gamma$ intersects the image of $\alpha$ or the image of $\beta$.

[image]

At any rate, I still strongly suspect that there must be a short algebraic-topological proof (and certainly one that does not rely on as much machinery as this argument does via Jordan Curve Theorem).

Comment: @ Travis Willse, I am accepting your first answer. In my original work, I have certain continuous injection which forces all the coordinates to be monotone! So both your and Mica's answers work in my situation. Basically, my work allows me to choose monotonic lifts using Path lifting lemma. I was wondering if this is true in general. That is, can we always choose a monotonic lift? Should I make a new question for it? And thank you for this wonderful approach using Jordan Curve theorem!

Comment: Okay, great, I'm glad my answers were useful (even if there's still a slick alg. top. solution that I'm pretty sure lurking out there). I'm not sure what your additional question is exactly, but either way I'd encourage you to post it as a new question. Once you do, add a hyperlink from one question to the other, which will automatically generate links between the questions on the sidebar.